# NTP - tos maxdist explained

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I had an issue with NTP today that I resolved by adding the line `tos maxdistance 30` to my `ntp.conf` file. I found this solution online and am now trying to understand exactly what this line means. I have done some reading on the ntp.conf documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37852/ntp-conf-5.html), and I still don't have a great understanding. According to the documentation, it looks like the `maxdistance` argument only takes values between 1-16, but I have found a lot of examples online of people using a value that is far greater than 16.

Can anybody explain this line to me, and why choosing a value above 16 makes any sense? I have tried searching online for an explanation, but haven't come across anything too helpful.

Answer (score 1):

See [the ntp documentation](https://www.ntp.org/documentation/4.2.8-series/miscopt/) on `tos maxdistance`:

> `tos`:
>
> This command alters certain system variables used by the the clock selection and clustering algorithms.
>
> `maxdistance`: Specify the synchronization distance threshold used by the clock selection algorithm. The default is 1.5 s. This determines both the minimum number of packets to set the system clock and the maximum roundtrip delay. *It can be decreased to improve reliability or increased to synchronize clocks on the Moon or planets*